# Updating a value in serializer after accessing .data in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-serializer

I have a serializer for my `Post` class which has a `image` and a `link` attribute.

`media` is an `FileField` and `link` is a `URLField` which is a url to somewhere else I share my post (in another website.)

I want to:

1. Submit my post data (text, and the image)
2. Accessing the url of submitted file to use in sharing it in another place.
3. Updating the `link` value after I found it.

This is what I tried:

```
post = PostCreateSerializer(data=request.data, context={'request': request})
post.is_valid(raise_excpetions=True)
post.save()
media_url = post.data.get('media')
link = find_link_value(media_url)
post.link = link
post.save()
```

This raises an exception. says:

```
 You cannot call `.save()` after accessing `serializer.data`.If you need to access data before committing to the database then inspect 'serializer.validated_data' instead.
```

The problem is when I use `post.validated_data.get('media')` instead of `.data`, it doesn't give me the url. It gives me an `InMemoryUploadedFile` object, that of course, doesn't have any path and url.

I thought I could use `name` attribute of `InMemoryUploadedFile` object to find the url (the one that will be created after `.save()`), but when the name is duplicate, the real name of file in disk and url differs from it's original name (for example, `name.jpg` and `name_aQySbJu.jpg`) and I can't use it for my purpose.

### Question

How can I have access to URL of that uploaded file, and also call `save()` after I updated my `post`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The serializer's **`save()`** method return corresponding instance. So, you can use that to get the url

```
post = PostCreateSerializer(data=request.data, context={'request': request})
post.is_valid(raise_excpetions=True)
post_instance = post.save()
media_url = post_instance.media.url
link = find_link_value()
post_instance.link = link
post_instance.save()
```

Comment: Thanks bro! I didn't knew about return value of `.save()`. accessing `media` attribute of `post_instance` gave me the path after `MEDIA_URL` and I had too add my host and my media_url to first of it to access full url. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

```
post = PostCreateSerializer(data=request.data, context={'request': request})
post.is_valid(raise_excpetions=True)
media_url = post.validated_data.get('media')
link = find_link_value()
post.save(link=link)
```

Actually, you can use this approach in order to save your post. When you pass link through serializer_obj.save(**kwargs) method it automatically pass your extra data into create(self, validated_data) or update(self, instance, validated_data) adding your extra data into validatad_data as dictionary. So than you can handle your extra data in create or update method of serializer.

Comment: My problem still is there. I don't have access to media_url using this approach (accessing `.validated_data` doesn't work, as described in question.) and if I replace it with `.data`, that exception raises again, altough I am calling `save()` with a keyword argument.

Comment: if `validated_data.get('media')` returns an object of file you can access the media url as `media=validated_data.get('media')` and then `media_url = media.url if media else None`. Then you can generate full url path using `request.build_absolute_uri(media_url)`

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it gives me __'InMemoryUploadedFile' object has no attribute 'url'.__ it only has `name` attribute which is realted to our business.

Comment: as I can see, `built_absolute_uri()` only appeds the file name to base url of request. right? in my case, this view is for url `/api/post` and my media are stored in `/media/<user>/<name>`. I think this function doesn't help me.

Comment: `built_absolute_uri()` method gets **url_path(ex: /media/image.jpg)** and generate **full address(ex: http://example.com//media/image.jpg)**